# Installing POV-Ray: configuration error

Tags: linux, boost, installation, povray

I am trying to install POV-Ray 3.7 stable version. I downloaded the source code from [github repo](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray/tree/3.7-stable).

I followed the instruction for unix system which is described in the [README file](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray/tree/3.7-stable/unix).

Unfortunately I get error message when I run configure command.

```
./configure COMPILED_BY="your name <email@address>"
```

The first error said that it could not find the boost library 1.37 or higher, so I installed the libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Now I can locate them as below:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py33.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.53.0
```

And I tried to run the configure again, and the error message is like this.

```
...
checking for boostlib >= 1.37... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... yes
checking whether the boost thread library is usable... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/povray-3.7-stable':
configure: error: cannot link with the boost thread library
See `config.log' for more details
```

So I put additional option `--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, but it wasn't successful either.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

The configure script was not able to find the library links properly. I am writing this, in case there's anyone who has the same problem.

```
./configure COMPILED_BY="name <email>" LIBS="-lboost_system -lboost_thread"
```

This solved my problem, and here's some other solutions. [POV-Ray Newsgroup]